# Is there a official release date for the Last Airbender 2

Tags: movie, avatar-the-last-airbender

I have found many websites, (like https://moviepilot.com/hashtags/AvatarTheLastAirbender) about there being a sequel to the fantasy film **Last Airbender**, but I can't find any release date. Can someone help? I'm not sure if any of these sites are solid sources.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by off-topic but what i'm trying to say is everyone is saying there's a sequel but i'm finding no real evidence of it, so i'm confused about if it's true or if people are just saying stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure why these links aren't working.

Answer (score 10):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Airbender_(2010_film)#Canceled_sequels) is usually a pretty good first place to check.

It currently says that M. Night Shyamalan’s last word on the subject was in [a 2015 interview with UK newspaper The Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2015/09/09/exclusive-m-night-shyamalan-to-make-another-thriller-before-the-last-airbender-2-5381979/), where he said an *Airbender* sequel *wouldn’t* be his next project (after 2015’s *The Visit*).

He’s since made [*Split*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(2016_American_film)), [*Glass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_(2019_film)), and [*Old*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_(film)). If an Airbender sequel depends on him (which, surprisingly, [it might do?](http://www.slashfilm.com/m-night-shyamalan-sequel-options/)), he might have space in his schedule for one, if he's not too busy executive-producing [*Servant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_(TV_series)) for  Apple TV+.

However, as of 2021, it cites the [October 2018 announcement of a live-action Netflix series](https://www.polygon.com/2018/9/18/17874344/avatar-the-last-airbender-live-action-series-netflix) as precluding any more movies for now. ([The creators did quit the project in 2020](https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/12/21365329/avatar-last-airbender-netflix-live-action-michael-dante-dimartino-bryan-konietzko-departure), but it is apparently still in development). There's also [more animated stuff under development at Nickelodeon](https://variety.com/2021/tv/news/avatar-last-airbender-legend-of-korra-nickelodeon-1234914149/).

Googling for "announced" and "release date" along with "Last Airbender 2" does indeed throw up a few articles that seem to assert that a sequel has been “confirmed”, but none of them feature any quotes from Shyamalan or anyone at Paramount confirming a sequel; nor do they link to any articles that do.

I’d rather not link to them, as it seems like they’re intentionally writing misleading headlines and crappy articles in an attempt to attract traffic from enthusiastic fans like yourself. But I’d suggest you ignore vcpost.com, movienewsguide.com and thebitbag.com in future, and stick to publications that report actual things that happen.

I’m not very up on movie news, but I think Variety and Slashfilm are pretty reliable papers of record. If [they](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22last+airbender+2%22+announced+site%3Avariety.com) [haven’t](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22last+airbender+2%22+announced+site%3Aslashfilm.com) reported a major studio movie announcement, it hasn’t happened.

The site you linked to, moviepilot.com, [does have a really good summary of statements made regarding a sequel](https://moviepilot.com/p/the-last-airbender-2-sequel-complete-history-m-night-shymalan/4239147) — none of which are commitments to actually making one.

Comment: The film received a critical bashing but made over $350m against a $120m budget, well within the financial range that would usually merit a sequel.

Comment: @Valorum: yeah, although I do wonder if studios expect more these days. *Amazing Spider-Man 2* did $709m on a $200m budget, but Sony still went running to Marvel for Spidey help.

Comment: @PaulDWaite - That budget included more than $100m of marketing though, which should have all but guaranteed a $1bn+ take at the Box Office. Imagine waking up Monday morning and finding that you're $300m short of where you told your boss you'd be.

Comment: @Valorum: Oh really? I didn’t realise Hollywood accounting included that stuff. They did seem to put up a lot of posters for Amazing 2. And it took less than its predecessor.

Comment: @PauldWaite - A lot of it's guesswork since the studios buy airtime and poster sites well in advance (often 3-5 years ahead in the case of billboards) of the movies actually being made but Spiderman 2 had vast amounts of publicity, maybe even as much as Rogue One

Comment: yes the making budget was $120m but $130m was spent on promoting the film which means it only made 100m profit well below what was expected.

Answer (score 3):

There won't be a sequel. In addition to the film being [critically panned](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/last_airbender), it also didn't do well enough financially to justify a sequel, let alone be the opening film of a series. Any faint hopes of a second or third film being made were finally dashed when Nickelodeon announced in 2018 that it was going to 'reenvision' the series as a live-action show.

> We’re thrilled for the opportunity to helm this live-action adaptation
> of Avatar: The Last Airbender. We can’t wait to realize Aang's world
> as cinematically as we always imagined it to be, and with a culturally
> appropriate, non-whitewashed cast. It's a once-in-a-lifetime chance to
> build upon everyone’s great work on the original animated series and
> go even deeper into the characters, story, action, and world-building.
>
> <sub><sup>[Avatar: The Last Airbender creators return for live-action Netflix remake](https://www.polygon.com/2018/9/18/17874344/avatar-the-last-airbender-live-action-series-netflix)</sup></sub>

---

For the record, while *The Last Airbender* didn't flop, neither did it do well. We now know that its budget was in the region of [$150M](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1516209665/). Add on on a marketing-spend of probably $50M (and take into account that the studio usually only gets about [50-60% of US box-office receipts](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/093015/how-exactly-do-movies-make-money.asp#:%7E:text=A%20studio%20might%20make%20about,the%20contract%20for%20each%20film.)), this means that its international box-office of $319M wouldn't have even covered Paramount's costs.

Having lost something around $30-50M, it's hard to see why they would want to make a second or third film, noting that while sequels usually do slightly *better* (at the box office) than the series opener, [they also tend to make smaller profits](https://contently.com/2016/04/18/sequel-paradox-11-charts/), which means that the studio would probably stand to lose *more* money, even if the second film gained a marginally larger audience.

Comment: Also the first film said, right in the title, that it was the _Last_ one. Filmmakers don't just [renege on promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_NeverEnding_Story_(film)#Possible_remake) like that!